# Solve to identify the intersection values of multiple constraints in OR tools

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, scip

I am working on a scheduling problem using Google OR Tools, such that when scheduling during the weekends, the requirement is to have same shifts as on last weekday. Let's say Friday - Early shift, then Saturday, Sunday - ['Early', 'Early'].

I am currently using Google OR Tools with Solver SCIP in the backend.

As an example, I am trying to solve it for first five weeks.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

emp = 5

tws = {}
for eind in range(emp):
    tws.update({eind: []})
for week in range(5):      
    for days in range(1,8):
        early = []
        late = []
        prev_day = (7*(week%2) + days) - 2
        curr_day = (7*(week%2) + days) - 1
    
        for i in range(emp):
            early.append(solver.IntVar(0,1,'es%d'%i))
            late.append(solver.IntVar(0,1,'ls%d'%i))

        if days < 6:
            if days <= 4:
                solver.Add(solver.Sum(early) <= (emp//2)+1)
                solver.Add(solver.Sum(early) >= emp//2)

                solver.Add(solver.Sum(late) <= emp//2)
                solver.Add(solver.Sum(late) >= (emp//2)-1)
            if days == 5:
                solver.Add(solver.Sum(early) == (emp//2)+1)

                solver.Add(solver.Sum(late) == emp//2)

            for i in range(emp):
                solver.Add(early[i]+late[i] <= 1)             

            if days == 1:
                if week == 0:
                    status = solver.Solve()
                    for sch in range(emp):
                        tws[sch].append([early[sch], late[sch]])
                    
                elif week > 0:                            
                    status = solver.Solve()
                    for sch in range(emp):
                        tws[sch].append([early[sch], late[sch]])

            elif days > 1:
                status = solver.Solve()
                for sch in range(emp):
                    tws[sch].append([early[sch], late[sch]])

        if days >= 6:
            solver.Add(solver.Sum(early) <= 1)
            solver.Add(solver.Sum(early) >= 1)
            solver.Add(solver.Sum(late) <= 1)
            solver.Add(solver.Sum(late) >= 1)  
            for e in range(emp):
                solver.Add(early[i] + late[i] <= 1)

            for i in range(emp):                  
                if days == 6:
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day][0] + tws[i][prev_day][1] + early[i] + late[i] <= 3)
                    solver.Add((tws[i][prev_day][0] + tws[i][prev_day][1]) - (early[i] + late[i]) >= 0)
                    solver.Add((tws[i][prev_day][0] + tws[i][prev_day][1]) - (early[i] + late[i]) <= 1)
                    solver.Add((tws[i][prev_day][0] - tws[i][prev_day][1]) - (early[i] - late[i]) >= -1)
                    solver.Add((tws[i][prev_day][0] - tws[i][prev_day][1]) - (early[i] - late[i]) <= 1)
                    solver.Add((tws[i][prev_day][0] + tws[i][prev_day][1])- early[i] >= -1)


                if days == 7:
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][0] + tws[i][prev_day][0] + early[i]  <= 3)
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][0] >= tws[i][prev_day][0])
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][0] >= early[i])
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][0] + late[i] <= 1)

                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][1] + tws[i][prev_day][1] + late[i] <= 3)
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][1] >=  late[i])
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][1] >=  tws[i][prev_day][1])
                    solver.Add(tws[i][prev_day-1][1] + early[i] <= 1)

                                
            solver.Solve()
            for sch in range(emp):
                tws[sch].append([early[sch], late[sch]])

        print(f"days: {(7*week) + days}")
        for es in early:            
            print(int(es.solution_value()), end = "\t")
        print("\n")
        for ls in late:
            print(int(ls.solution_value()), end = "\t")
        print("\n")
```

I get the output as follows,

```
days: 5
1  1  1  0  0
0  0  0  1  1
days: 6
1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  1
days: 12
0  0  1  1  1
1  1  0  0  0
days: 13
1  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0
```

For each day, the first row shows the early shift for each employee, whereas the second row represents the late shift for the employees (Max - 3 early shift, 2 late shifts on a day, where early is always more than late shifts).
Early shifts must not follow the late shifts and vice-versa on Friday, Saturday and Sunday. I check the constraints based on previous day early, previous day late, current day early, and current day late shifts. It is allowed to have only one early and one late shifts during the weekends.

Each previous day early, previous day late, current day early, current day late can have either '0' or '1'.
First Row depicts - '1' means Early, and '0' represents No early shift
Second row depicts - '1' means Late, and '0' represents No Late shift

A list of previous day early, previous day late, current day early, current day late can have total 16 possibilities.
Optimal result is,
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0]]
whereby considering each elements as a bit, then feasible result is {0,4,5,8,10} (Assumption - sum of bits).

Constraints:

```
(Previous day early + previous day late) + (current day early + current day late) <= 3
(Previous day early + previous day late) - (current day early + current day late) >= 0
Feasible result - {0,4,5,6,8,9,10} (Assumption - sum of bits)
(Previous day early - previous day late) - (current day early - current day late) >= -1
(Previous day early - previous day late) - (current day early - current day late) >= 1
Feasible Result - {0,4,5,6,7,8,10} (Assumption - sum of bits)
(Previous day early + previous day late) - (current day early) >= -1
(Previous day early + previous day late) - (current day early) >= 1
Feasible Result - {0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10} (Assumption - sum of bits)
```

Upon adding all these constraints, The optimal result I must get is {0,4,5,8,10} (Assumption - sum of bits)

But after feeding all these constraints to the Google OR Tools, I get an inappropriate result on day 13, which I shared above.

I think that logically, I must get an optimal result, but I could not get it. Could I get some help in solving this? Any kind of information would be thankful.

Comment: Is your Saturday day 6 and Sunday day 7?  If you require that weekend shifts must have the same shifts as on last weekday (Friday), then how could a situation arise where on Saturday, early shifts would follow late shifts on Friday? (I assume you meant "follow" and not "be followed by"). Saturday and Sunday would require late shifts if Friday had a late shift, wouldn't they?

Comment: Why are you performing the Solve inside the loop that establishes the constraints? It is being called once for each week. Shouldn't it be called only once after all the variables and constraints for the whole problem have been added?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins I tried to solve for each day by defining the variables for each iteration. After solving for each day, I stored the solution in a set of lists. Then I access the previous day values from the stored set on each Saturday, and Sunday to define the constraints. Yes, Early shift must not follow the late shifts and vice-versa (on each Saturday and Sunday - Friday, Saturday and Sunday must have same shifts) (Thanks for mentioning it...). I modified it accordingly..

Comment: If each week can be solved separately from the others, you should create a new Solver for each week, solve the week, then proceed to the next. As you've implemented it here, the variables and constraints accumulate from week to week in the single Solver. The call to Solve respects all the previous constraints and delivers a _different_ solution on each call.

Comment: One more idea: if Friday, Saturday and Sunday all have the same shifts, you don't really need any new variables for Saturday and Sunday, you can use Friday's variables for those days.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I would try to create a new solver for each week to get the solution. I could understand now the considerations of the solver while generating the solution. Actually, the constraints vary on Friday to Saturday and Sunday. On Friday more than one employee is allowed to work in Early and Late shifts, whereas on Weekends, only one employee can work in Early and Late shifts. That is the reason, I try to define new variables.